# Why does Go io.MultiWriter fail to write all data equally?

Tags: go

I am trying to get a list of files from the `fd` (`find`) utility and pass them to `fzf` while simultaneously saving that list to a text file on the hard disk. In the following code, everything is passed from `fd` to `fzf` just fine, but not all of the results make it to the text file. Why is this? The number of results that make it to the text file varies each time I run the code (the total number of lines output by `fd` is about 1200, but the text file will only ever receive between 200 to 900 of those lines).

```
fdFile, _ := os.OpenFile("./fd-output.txt", os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE|os.O_TRUNC, 0600)
defer fdFile.Close()

find := exec.Command("fd", ".", "/etc")
fzf := exec.Command("fzf")
fzf.Stderr = os.Stderr

r, w := io.Pipe()
find.Stdout = w
fzf.Stdin = r
var fzfSelection bytes.Buffer
fzf.Stdout = &fzfSelection

find.Start()
go func() {
    outs := []io.Writer{fdFile, w}
    io.Copy(io.MultiWriter(outs...), r)
}()

fzf.Start()
find.Wait()
w.Close()
fzf.Wait()
fmt.Print(fzfSelection.String())
```

I read somewhere that my issue sounds like some of the data is not being flushed to the file. However, I have tried appending `.Flush()` to every reader/writer in the above code and always get an error that tells me the method does not exist.

Comment: The problem is that you spawn a routine but do not synchronize it with the caller to prevent the program from quitting before the routine has executed entirely. It is also a little weird that you have put `w` as a destination copy of `r`, because it is the destination of `w` to begin with (you know it is a pipe of which you read what you write, until it closes). anyway, i figure you are looking for that `find.Stdout = io.MultiWriter(fdFile, w)`. I hope that will make it, i was not able to reproduce.

Comment: @mh-cbon When I try your suggestion, the file generally doubles in size for some reason (duplicating lines). I also tried adding a channel to wait for the goroutine to finish. The problem is, if `w` never closes, the goroutine will never finish. How can I verify the goroutine has finished writing all output from `fd` before closing `w`?

Comment: add a sync.WaitGroup or use an exit channel as the last line of your code, and send the signal from last line of your go routine.